# Getting data from Form type cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view, which lists out contacts. On tapping edit cell reloads and presents labels as text inputs. I need to have save button on top right, so when I tap on save how can I get the updated inputs from Cell ? Since action is triggered from outside I need to send a message to cell some how.

For now I am getting the data using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and by accessing cells properties.

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"id "forIndexPath:editCellIdx];
NSString *input 1 = cell.labelOne.text; ... and so on
```

Is there any better way ?

Comment: I think you should be modifying the model immediately text is editted.  So if the user decides not to save the data you need to abandon the half-edited model and basically do nothing.  So when you go into edit mode, take a *copy* of the model and when saving, overwrite the original model with the edited model.

Comment: @trojanfoe I had a similar thought. Instead of exposing model to View. I could write a interface which would delegate back the text after editing, and view controller would keep updating the model with the text. Is it an overkill to use delegate like this or this is better than dequeing atleast ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the edited data in NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableArray. And then reload the tableview data.

You can get the edited texts of textfields from following method

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   NSString *cellEditedText = textField.text;
  // save this text in dictionary or array. 
}

- (void)saveData
{
  [tableview reloadData];
}
```